# Passing value from one form to another using events in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to pass a value from one form, let's call it Form1 to another form, Form2. When i double click a row in a listview that is in Form2, the value should be passed to a combobox in Form1.

I could get one of my other forms to do this using an event called PropertyChanged, but I can't seem to get it to work on other forms. I don't know if it is the fact that you can only have 1 event in the entire project and not have another with the same name. I'm missing something, but i just don't know where.

### This is the code i used in Form2:

```
Public Event PropertyChanged As Action(Of Object)

Private Sub ListView2_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e as EventArgs) Handles ListView2.DoubleClick
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text)
End Sub
```

### And this is the code I used in Form1:

```
 Dim WithEvents f2 As Form2

 Private Sub PropertyChanged(obj As Object) Handles f2.PropertyChanged
     cmb_form1.Text = obj
 End Sub
```

Comment: Form2 is "owned" by Form1, which means that Form1 can see Form2's public properties. If you pass Form1 to Form2 at instantiation, the reverse will also be true.

Comment: Is Form2 a modal window existing only for the sake of choosing a value then being closed?

Comment: When I double click a row in Form2's listview, it closes and passes the value to a combobox in form1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to implement this. This one is quick and dirty.

It consists of writing up a property in Form2 which is public. When the user makes a choice, it goes in the property. Then Form1 reads the property before it disposes Form2.

Here's a little code snippet to better illustrate what I mean:

```
Public Class Form1
    ' This form has a button which opens a Form2 instance
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim form2 As New Form2 ' instantiate Form2
        form2.ShowDialog() ' the user chooses a value
        MessageBox.Show(form2.Result) ' get it before it's out of scope!
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Public Property Result As String ' the value is stored in there, it can be any type

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Result = "Clicked!" ' store the value you want to share between forms
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Have fun!

Comment: in form2, it closes whenever I double click a value, so this property Result is where my value will be stored, so in Form1, I just need to call that property when the Form2 closes, and I can do that using cmbform1,text = form2.result?

Comment: How do i do it so when the Form2 closes it places the value in the Result property inside of the combobox in Form1

Comment: @StewieL It won't do it automatically if written this way, but before the end of the scope where you instantiate Form2 you can use the `Result` value directly from From2 (that's why it's public). That's what I do on the line where I write `get it before it's out of scope!`. I can add a way to make it Form2 changing it into Form1 if you really need to by passing Form1 to Form2, but you shouldn't need that if Form2 is shown as a dialog like in this example.

Comment: So basically Form1 does all the work: 1- instantiate Form2, 2- get the value from Form2 after the user is done choosing, 3- put it in the combobox. All in the same Sub.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for being so patience. Have a nice day!

Comment: Another thing. I have a home form, called Main. It is a Mdi Container, and i want to make Form2 parent set to this form, but I can't because an error pops up. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: @StewieL You can choose which form your project will launch. From this form you can manage the rest of your stuff. [Here's how to do it:](https://imgur.com/a/GkgRmD9) `1- Right click on your project (not the solution)` `2- Open the properties window` `3- Look for the "Application" settings` `4- Choose the form you want to instantiate when you start your project.` Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @StewieL I just saw your other post and realize I didn't read you right. I'll reply in your other thread with something which makes sense.

Comment: This is not a quick and dirty solution. It's the proper way to do it.